# Windows Server 2012 on ESXi slow to respond on network after reboot

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-esxi

Running guest Windows Server 2012 R2 with Exchange 2016 in an ESXi 6.0 host. The issue I'm experiencing is a long time it takes for the server to start responding after each reboot. The guest will reboot, come up, allow me to log in and interact with it. However, it will takes several minutes (~10) past that before the server starts responding to external clients, even an RDP login. The built-in soft firewall is disabled on the domain network since I have a hardware firewall at the gateway.

When I log into the console right after a reboot but before the server is responsive on the network, any network-relate features such as the "Network and Sharing Center" or "Windows Firewall" don't come up. Blank windows just sit there for a few minutes in a "loading" phase and then they come up simultaneously to the server becoming responsive on the network.

I have another 2012 Server on the SAME esxi host and that one works fine! It's just this one with Exchange on it.

Guest: 2 x QuadCore Intel Xeons 2.266GHz / 32 GB RAM / 500 GB Storage

Adding results of Jetstress here as opposed to "comment" since those cannot be formatted, even with newlines:

Test Summary
  Overall Test Result   Pass

Total I/O Performance
  I/O Database Reads/sec ~ 40.011
  I/O Database Writes/sec ~ 21.361
  I/O Database Reads Average Bytes ~ 84678.508
  I/O Database Writes Average Bytes ~ 36612.187
  I/O Log Reads/sec ~ 0.047
  I/O Log Writes/sec ~ 5.632
  I/O Log Reads Average Bytes ~ 2893.820
  I/O Log Writes Average Bytes ~ 11454.790

Comment: Be sure you have the RAM good enough (4Go for windows server).

Comment: This is VERY odd, we have lots of 2012R2 VMs that are as quick as we like - can you give us much more detail please - host CPU/mem/storage, VM definition, network setup etc.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange is really hard on IOPS. It slow down all service to start.

I see that symptom often when Exchange is virtualized and that the storage controller is lacking power.

For one customer I have I was lucky and I was able to order memory for his storage controller, as without it it used to make the same symptom as you have. (with the memory it was better, but still slow, the server was not planned big enough)

Try [Microsoft Jetstress 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=36849) (it work for 2016) and get a IOPS reports please.

To read the test result; [Jetstress 2013 Field Guide v2.0.0.9](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Jetstress-2013-Field-Guide-2438bc12)  >> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Jetstress-2013-Field-Guide-2438bc12/file/153482/1/Jetstress%20Field%20Guide%20v2.0.0.9.docx

A char example for above's document;

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. Just ran Jetstress. My results look a bit different than the screenshot you posted so I'm not sure how to read this thing. Here is an example of a few tables but I'm not sure what to look for, exactly.

Comment: @prl77  thanks for the feedback, you can add it to your questiin, you got more editing tool to keep the layout :)

Comment: Edited the original post, as you suggested.

Comment: any advise? Does anything jump out at you?

Comment: @prl77 thanks for the edit, I will try to get a result from a server in lab tomorrow to compare, as the result you have seem high, thus it's a bad sign..

Comment: Any luck @yagmoth555 ?